# How can I include a script defined in Theme to a view from Modules in Orchard

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms

I define styles for all different modules in the theme. Each CSS file in the Styles folder in the theme belongs to a certain module.  Only theme knows which file is which. I want my view in the module to include a style defined in the theme via Style.Require. As far as only theme knows the exact css file I can only do it indirectly using the name associated with the resource at the level of theme. The problem is that when I use that name in module it cannot be resolved. So is there any way to do this trick in Orchard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, what worked for me is:

In a view in the module use

```
Style.Require("SomeStyleTobeDefinedInTheme");
```

In the `ResourceManifest` in the theme add

```
var manifest = builder.Add();
manifest.DefineStyle("SomeStyleTobeDefinedInTheme").SetUrl("themed-module.css");
```

**Important! Do not define the style in the `ResourceManifest` in the module!**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Style.Require`, use `Style.Include` and provide a path to some stylesheet like this:

```
@{
    Style.Include(Html.ThemePath(WorkContext.CurrentTheme,
                                 "/Styles/my-module-stylesheet.css");
}
```

You don't have to define resources for this to work.